# Проблемы с установкой MAUI

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Делал по [официальному гайду](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/first-app) от майкрософт, не помогло, смотрел другие статьи, читал комментарии, но типа проектов MAUI (как на скрине с msdn) у меня все равно нет, а если извращаться с [dotnet командами](https://dev.to/melissahoughton/getting-started-with-net-maui-1dg), то создать проект получается, но он в упор не признает свои пространства имен и кидает ошибки. Пробовал на VS19 и VS22 комьюнити и на VS22 про. В случае 22 студий, в инсталлере хотя бы есть чекбоксы с MAUI, но никак ничего не меняется.

Answer (score 0):

MAUI так и не вышел до настоящего времени в статусе пред релиз, что бы получить возможность работать с такими изменениями нужно изменить источник обновления студии в установщике и дышать свободно, я описанных проблем не наблюдаю, пожалуй кроме проблем с освоением самого решения.
[image: Изменение источника обновлений]

Comment: опишите, пожалуйста, словами, то, что вы предлагаете.

Comment: Словами описано, изменить источник обновления все достаточно однозначно.